# Limitar Resultado de Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Estou com um problema há alguns dias. Tenho um select que faz alguns inners e deve retornar 3 linhas, porém um dos inners possui diversos resultados vinculados ao resultado pesquisado; como limitar para esse inner pegar apenas o primeiro resultado e o select continuar retornando as 3 linhas?

```
    SELECT `imovel`.`imvValorImovel`, `imovel`.`imvCodigo`, 
          `imovel`.`broCodigo`, `imovel`.`imvDormitorio`, `imovel`.`imvSuite`, 
          `imovel`.`tpoCodigo`, `imovel`.`imvGaragem`, `bairro`.`broNome`, 
          `tipo`.`tpoNome`, `imagem_imovel`.`imaNome` 
    FROM  `imovel` 
    INNER JOIN  `bairro` ON  `imovel`.`broCodigo` =  `bairro`.`broCodigo` 
    INNER JOIN  `tipo` ON  `imovel`.`tpoCodigo` =  `tipo`.`tpoCodigo`
    INNER JOIN  `bairro` ON  `imovel`.`broCodigo` =  `bairro`.`broCodigo`
    INNER JOIN  `imagem_imovel` ON  `imovel`.`imvCodigo` =  `imagem_imovel`.`imvCodigo 
    WHERE  `imovel`.`broCodigo` = "'.$resultado->broCodigo.'" 
    AND `imovel`.`tpoCodigo` = "'.$resultado->tpoCodigo.'" 
    AND `imovel`.`imvFinalidade` = "'.$resultado->imvFinalidade.'"
    LIMIT 3
```

Comment: qual inner retorna mais que um resultado ? qual limitação será aplicada ?

Comment: o ultimo, com imagem_imovel, a limitação é de pegar apenas um resultado desta tabela e continuar executando a query.

Answer (score 2):

Para filtrar resultados repetidos num join você pode usar um `group by`. Por exemplo, vamos supor que a tabela que tenha registros duplicados pro mesmo imóvel seja a `imagem_imovel`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse caso, existe apenas o imóvel "1" com duas imagens: img1 e img2. Para recuperar a maior imagem, você vai precisar criar uma subquery no seu join:

```
select * from imovel join bairro using (broCodigo) join tipo using (tpoCodigo) join (select max(imvNome), imvCodigo from imagem_imovel group by imvCodigo) maioresImagens using (imvCodigo);
```

Perceba que ao invés de fazer o join na tabela `imagem_imovel` foi feito um join com uma consulta que retorna os maiores nomes dessa tabela (max(imvNome)) para cada imóvel (group by imvCodigo). O resto da consulta permanece e agora o resultado será:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O importante aqui é saber fazer uso das subqueries sempre que você tiver uma limitação nos resultados de um join.

Comment: Funciona! Porém é meio inviavel, a consulta leva 22 segundos para trazer resultados (testata diretamente no banco).

Comment: Sim, a consulta vai ficar mais complexa mesmo, impactando no plano de execução. Uma forma de otimizar seria usar a consulta que traz tudo e tratar o maior resultado no código mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

nessa caso, acho que caberia apenas um sub-select:

```
SELECT 
  `imovel`.`imvValorImovel`, 
  `imovel`.`imvCodigo`, 
  `imovel`.`broCodigo`, 
  `imovel`.`imvDormitorio`, 
  `imovel`.`imvSuite`, 
  `imovel`.`tpoCodigo`, 
  `imovel`.`imvGaragem`, 
  `bairro`.`broNome`, 
  `tipo`.`tpoNome`,
   (SELECT  
     `imagem_imovel`.`imaNome`
    FROM `imagem_imovel` 
    WHERE `imagem_imovel`.`imvCodigo` = `imovel`.`imvCodigo` 
    ORDER BY `imagem_imovel`.`imvCodigo`  
    LIMIT 1) as `imaNome`
FROM  `imovel` 
INNER JOIN  `bairro` ON  `imovel`.`broCodigo` =  `bairro`.`broCodigo` 
INNER JOIN  `tipo` ON  `imovel`.`tpoCodigo` =  `tipo`.`tpoCodigo`
INNER JOIN  `bairro` ON  `imovel`.`broCodigo` =  `bairro`.`broCodigo`
WHERE  `imovel`.`broCodigo` = "'.$resultado->broCodigo.'" 
AND `imovel`.`tpoCodigo` = "'.$resultado->tpoCodigo.'" 
AND `imovel`.`imvFinalidade` = "'.$resultado->imvFinalidade.'"
LIMIT 3
```